# Almost everywhere convergence to a function, then the function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis

Let's say that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions from $(X, \mathcal{F})$ to $(\bar{\mathbb{R}}, \mathcal{B}( \mathbb{\bar{R}} ))$ such that $f_n(x) \uparrow f(x)$ almost everywhere. Does that imply that $f$ is measurable?

In general, I'm working on Dudley's statement that says that we can substitute $f_n(x) \uparrow f(x)$ for all $x \in X$ for the weaker statement $f_n(x) \uparrow f(x)$ almost everywhere in $X$, or also that we can change (for some measurable function h) $f_n(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x \in X$ for $f_n(x) \leq h(x)$ almost everywhere in X, in some convergence theorems.

My work is as follows: if $C$ is a set of measure zero, we can redefine, for example, $f_n(x) \leq h(x)$ almost everywhere in $X$ for $g_n(x)=f_n(x)$ if $x \in X \setminus C$ and $f_n(x)= h(x)$ for $x \in C$. This new $g_n$ is measurable because we can paste measurable functions with disjoints measurable domains and we get $g_n(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

But in the case of $f_n(x) \uparrow f(x)$ almost everywhere in $X$, I want to define $g_n(x) = f_n(x)$ for $x \in X \setminus C$ and $g_n(x)=f(x)$ for $x \in C$. But I can't guarantee that this new $g_n$ is measurable because I don't know if $f$ is measurable on $C$. So I want to know if $f$ is measurable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just redefine $f_n$ zero over $C$, then you get an increasing sequence of measurable functions.